# NetSuite Saved Search Formula

Tags: java, javascript, sql, netsuite

How can you get the debit amount of GL Impact by using the saved search? Here is my code I'm using custom record and **custrecord_agri_feedd_ialink** is the Inventory Adjustment value.

```
CASE WHEN {custrecord_agri_feedd_parent.custrecord_agri_feedd_chxgender} IN 'Female' THEN {custrecord_agri_feedd_parent.custrecord_agri_feedd_ialink.debitamount} END
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CASE WHEN {custrecord_agri_feedd_parent.custrecord_agri_feedd_chxgender} IN 'Female' THEN {custrecord_agri_feedd_parent.custrecord_agri_feedd_ialink.debitamount}

You need not to use IN. Just use (=) equal sign for this and put in the ELSE condition as well.